# nx lib responsible for environment fileReplacements not working

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

- I have this lib, `@my-proj/common` which  `export * from './lib/environment';` in its `index.ts`
- my frontend (ng) and backend(express // nest) apps `import { environment } from '@my-proj/common'`;
- when I build these apps only dev vars are used. ie `npx nx build angular-app --prod`;
- I thought since I was building with the prod flag it would use `environment.prod.ts`  from `@my-proj/common` ?

Project configuration:

```
"common": {
  "root": "libs/common",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/common/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/node:package",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "libs/common/src/lib/environment.ts",
              "with": "libs/common/src/lib/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/libs/common",
        "tsConfig": "libs/common/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "packageJson": "libs/common/package.json",
        "main": "libs/common/src/index.ts",
        "assets": ["libs/common/*.md"]
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not possible to do file replacement on libs. You could do the file replacements from the app configuration or make for example your lib configurable with a static forRoot method in the exposed module